# Hilt dependency implementation in multi-module development

Tags: android-studio, gradle, multi-module, dagger-hilt, modularization

I have created a module named *dependencies* where I have put all depConstraints I need so I don't have to implement the dependency in each module individually.

I have added Hilt dependencies in my depConstraints's*gradle* file but when I want to use Hilt in another module I get the following error

```
Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android dependency was found.
```

Is there a way to use the *depConstraints* module's dependencies in my other modules (for example *app* module) without implementing them individually in each module's scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may not mean what it says. It pops up when *anything* with gradle files is wrong and obscures the real error.

Try to comment out hilt plugin import and hilt block (if exists) inside build.gradle file, then Sync Project with Gradle files - most of the time there will be another error.

I spent so much time thinking hilt was the issue, but actually it never was.